# koma-script: spacing in table of contents

Tags: spacing, koma-script, line-spacing

Every space, e.g. ...

- ...between "Contents" and "1 One",
- ...between "1 One" and "1.1 bla",
- ...between "1.1 bla" and "1.2 bla" and
- ...between "1.2 bla" and "2 Two",
- ...

in the TOC should be `0.5cm`.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4,pagesize=auto,headsepline,parskip=full,fleqn]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}

\section{bla}

\section{bla}

\chapter{Two}

\section{bla}

\section{bla}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,headsepline,parskip=full,fleqn]{scrbook}

\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{%
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=false}% no parskip in ToC
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1sp minus 1sp]{chapter}% no skip after ToC title
}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=.5cm]{chapter}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=.5cm]{section}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=.5cm]{default}{subsection}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\Blindtext

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]